# npm install (--save-def) does not add the module into devDependencies

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to get used to GruntJS and when I install a package for my app it doesn't add the dependencies to the package.json. I followed the "Get Started" section from the GruntJS site and NPM installs the module in my app directory.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `npm install [plugin] --save-dev`

Subject says `--save-def`

Comment: Could you possibly expand on this answer?

Comment: The title of this post has --save-def (def vs. dev). My first guess was this isn't working due to the typo.

`npm install [module to install] --save-dev` would install the from NPM and save it to the package.json file for devDependencies